# "Scratch-work" synonym

Tags: synonyms, mathematics

Mathematicians often have to perform calculations on paper (maybe often is an understatement). To describe this, I have always referred to it as "scratch-work". Is there any alternate way I could refer to this in a more formal or professional way?

Comment: This whole time I've been using *back-of-the-envelope calculations* to refer to these, but because of this question I now realize that [those are meant to describe *estimations* **not** scratch-work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation). Good question!

Comment: Scratch paper and paper are descriptions of paper. Not of mathematical calculations. Also, why would such a thing be more formal or professional??

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps **work notes**. This can refer to a wide range of preparatory material in fields beyond mathematics.

Comment: Linguists rarely calculate that much, but they find themselves always making lists, of words or sounds or sentences, and often jotting down random associations with particular constructions. These sometimes surface as squibs. [Haj Ross's squibs](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Squibnet/) are famous for this

Answer (score 2):

You can use the word *scribble*, both as a noun and a verb.

The noun definition in *[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scribble)*:

> a piece of writing or a drawing that is done quickly or carelessly

Here are, at least, two usages I've found in a formal mathematics context in Google Books: [1](https://books.google.es/books?id=3-JBEAAAQBAJ&pg=PR21&dq=math+%22scribbles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjixK_eocv4AhUKRBoKHZ0XBqEQ6AF6BAgGEAI#v=onepage&q=math%20%22scribbles%22&f=false), [2](https://books.google.es/books?id=JWM-CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&dq=math+%22scribbles%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiY9p6losv4AhUk5IUKHTTsCqI4ChDoAXoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=math%20%22scribbles%22&f=false)

If you search *math scribbles*, *mathematical scribbles* etc. you can find relevant results and images as well. *Scribble* is not a colloquial/informal word by itself but it can be used in that way depending on the context. I've included some usages in formal context also. Additionally, The OP mentioned the following in a comment: "The situation I am describing is like when you are given a word problem, and quickly write 50*8 = 400 on a piece of scratch paper. The "50 * 8 = 400" written is called the *scratch-work*."

Answer (score 0):

[Draft](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draft) comes to mind

> An early version of a written work
> I have to revise the first draft of my term paper.
>
> A preliminary sketch, rough outline
> His first drafts were better than most authors' final products.

Comment: I don't think draft works.. The situation I am describing is like when you are given a word problem, and quickly write 50*8 = 400 on a piece of scratch paper. The "50 * 8 = 400" written is called the scratch-work; I don't think this is a draft.